# Trigger subtracting quantity for each time, not specific row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have created a trigger, & the aim was when i update the quantity in one table 'Sales', the 'Product' table would then minus that quantity against that one product.

I created the below trigger, however, when i update the quantity field in the sales table of i.e 1, the trigger will minus 1 (in the quantity) field against every single row in the product table. Not just the one i require

```
create trigger salesins after 
insert on sales for each row 
update product set stocklev=stocklev-new.qty;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE` or `UPDATE` updates all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you didn't specify a `WHERE` clause for the `UPDATE`. Assuming you have 2 tables: `sales` & `product`. `sales` table has a field `product_id` which is a foreign key to `product` table primary key `id`. Then the trigger could be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER salesins AFTER INSERT ON sales FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE product SET stocklev = stocklev - new.qty
    WHERE id = new.product_id;
```

Comment: Prefect. Thank you!

Comment: @TBERMINGHAM most welcome, glad that I could help :)